# Знак вопроса или точка?

Tags: пунктуация

*Спросил у него знаками, можно ли войти(?)*

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Это повествовательное сложноподчинённое предложение, точка. Он же не спрашивает: Спросил у него знаками?

Со знаком вопроса была бы прямая речь: *Спросил у него знаками: "Можно  войти?"*